# Axle with Square Edges and Round ends?

Tags: tools

This is a picture of the underside of my weed whacker/eater.  I'm wanting to purchase the "socket" which connects to the Axle below.  But I'm not sure what you would call this part.  Can someone help me out ?  Thanks in Advance, Patrick

Edit to clarify - Just the small part that would fit directly around the Axle.

[image]

"Socket":
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the part foremost in your image then a quality adjustable spanner (with parallel faces) is what I use, with an open end spanner on the flats on the shaft which will be below the cable device held on by that nut.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have added a picture of the receiver / socket.  Do the metal parts have a name ?  If I wanted to purchase something like this what would they be called ?  Or is this a custom / non-standard item ?

Comment: If you want the item in you second image then manufacturer / dealer. If you want a "socket" to turn the other part then afaik you will need to get that made.

Comment: Thanks - I'm trying to attach a different (metal and non-compatible) blade - but need to be able to source and then wield that strange metal central part.  (I don't want to change/damage what I've got - as am just experimenting with super-charging my weed-whacker :-).)